# Is using Try/Catch to pseudo-synchronously make Asynchronous API calls proper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor, async-await

I am wondering if this is the proper way to achieve what I am trying to do.

1. `POST` Schedule to database
2. `GET` Items that relate to Schedule ( Must be done after schedule `POST` )

Should each operation have be a `Task` and I call both task from `OnPostAsync()?`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || _context.Schedules == null || Schedule == null)
        return Page();
    try
    {
        _context.Schedules.Add(Schedule);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            Items = await _context.BoMItems.Include(m => m.Item)
                .Where(m => m.BOMId == Schedule.BOMId)
                .Where(m => m.IsRunnerItem == true)
                .ToArrayAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    
}
```

This is the only thing I have came up with. I've read into Tasks last night, but I need more understanding.

Comment: No, it is not proper to _ever_ have a `try/catch` with an empty `catch` block - you shouldn't `catch` exceptions unless you're going to gracefully handle-or-rethrow exceptions: never swallow them.

Comment: Wrap with try/catch only those pieces of code where you expect errors. `_context.Schedules.Add(Schedule);` - what error is expected here? Bad control flow detected.

Comment: @Dai Please, I am asking another question. I emptied the catch blocks before posting it here.

Comment: @Ryan Did you read my post? I need to POST before making a call, ASYNC

Comment: Where is a the request performed from? A web client?

Comment: @alapaah request is performed on web client, Razor page.

Comment: Then I would implement some logic that performs the POST request to create a schedule, when that's completed perform the GET request.

Comment: @alapaah Exactly. The try/catch is the best logic I could come up with.

Comment: One setup could be that if you do it from the client side you can perform you can run the request, then check the status code from the request with a simple if statement. If it's 201 created perform the get request. HttpResponseMessage postrequest = await client.PostAsync(<url>) if(request.IsSuccessSTatusCode) {HttpResponseMessage getrequest = await client.GetAsync(<url>);
}

Comment: Why do you think you need the try/catch at all? If what you want is to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before doing anything further (which is what your title suggests to me), `await` already does that for you.

Comment: @madreflection I explained very in detail in the post. The operation may not complete before anything else. The await keyword does not force order, it's just waiting on the thread to return. So if you had two variables with await, they would return at different times given the data load.

Comment: Nope. The entire purpose of the `await` keyword is to wait for the task to complete. If you have `await task1; await task2;`, they will complete *in that order*. If those are method calls -- `await Method1(); await Method2();` -- then `Method2` will not be called until `Method1` returns a task and that task is completed. Your explanation is predicated on that not being the case.

Comment: public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
 Task.Run(() =>
 {
  _context.Schedules.AddAsync(Schedule);
 }).Wait();
 await Task.Run(async () =>
 {
  Items =  await _context.BoMItems.Include(m => m.Item)
   .Where(m => m.BOMId == Schedule.BOMId)
   .Where(m => m.IsRunnerItem == true)
   .ToArrayAsync();       
 });
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Comment: @madreflection *"If you have `await task1; await task2;`, they will complete in that order."* -- No, the `task2` might complete before the `task1`. The order of awaiting has nothing to do with the order of completion.

Comment: PackJC in case you have found a solution to your problem, you can post it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Embedding an answer inside the body of the question is frowned upon here.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Conceded. I wrote that part off the cuff. I meant that execution won't pass that point until the task is completed which, as you mentioned, could happen sooner. The point was to make OP understand that it wasn't going to pass the `await` keyword if it *wasn't* completed. OP seemed to believe that it could.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I don't have 15 reputation needed to answer my own question. I was also downvoted when half of the comments didn't even respond to the question. I am frowning at this experience.

Comment: OK, I did it for you. The downvotes are most likely the result of the empty `catch` blocks. People strongly dislike swallowing exceptions, and rightly so.

Comment: @TheodorZouliasDid you read about the part where I removed parts of the method to increase readability on the problem?

Comment: What is written in the comments doesn't matter. The comments are intended for asking for more information about the question, or for suggesting improvements for the question. Any additional information should be added in the question by editing it. People should be able to evaluate a question without reading the comments.

Comment: Also the code in a question is supposed to be minimal. If you omitted the error handling because it is not important, then you could omit the `try`/`catch` too. Leave in the question just the minimal amount of code that is important for demonstrating the problem that has to be solved.

Answer (score -1):

The code below was posted by the OP as a solution to the problem. Currently the OP has not sufficient reputation to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) their question.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _context.Schedules.AddAsync(Schedule);
    }).Wait();
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Items =  await _context.BoMItems.Include(m => m.Item)
            .Where(m => m.BOMId == Schedule.BOMId)
            .Where(m => m.IsRunnerItem == true)
            .ToArrayAsync();       
    });
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```